# How-to create .dmg file (python source code + packages) on Mac?

Tags: macos, dmg

hope someone can help me. I have code a pyqt4 program. That is using a lot of packages, like Qt4, HDF5, qimage2ndarray, and, and, and. Now I want to create a .dmg file that contains everything you need to run that program. If you have a clean installation of Mac OS X, you only need to run this .dmg and you have everything installed you need. 
How can I do that on a Mac? Asking google, I got a lot how-tos to create .dmg files, but only for a folder or a .app. But I need the packages to. So how am I doing that? 
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you'd rather need to make a package than a .dmg file (see here: http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html) - it's an old tutorial, but you should get the deal

Comment: Oooh damn, of course dmg is only a disk image. So stupid of me. Thank you very much slhck

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider two possibilities:

- Installing dependencies on the target computer, for *all* applications, not just yours: then you need to go for the .pkg route (to be later delivered as .dmg, or as .zip)
- Embedding dependencies in your application bundle, so that you can provide, again, a .zip or .dmg with your app to be dragged to any folder.